# ida pro sigstop android mediaserver

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, ida

I have to debug libmedia.so on Android 5.1 (LG G4) with kernel 3.10. I use IDA Pro 6.8. After I'm attached to the mediaserver process, in the segment view, IDA shows the code segment of libmedia.so with exact starting and ending addresses (controlled in /proc/pid/maps) but the routine's addresses of libmedia.so are outside the code segment of the libmedia.so. Ignoring that and going on with debugging, I set a breakpoint at the startInput routine, called when the microphone is needed.  After setting the breakpoint, IDA returns:

> F75EC260: got SIGSTOP signal (Stop unblockable) (exc.code 13, tid 8552)

The address 0xF75EC260 is in the libc.so and corresponds to instruction:

> svc 0

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there any anti-debug protection in Android 5.1? In previous versions of Android, there are no problems with debugging.